# Ao clicar em um item do select, mostrar input

Tags: javascript, html, select, input

Quero que quando eu clicar no select "OUTROS" apareça ao lado um input, mas até agora sem sucesso.

Meu código *HTML e JS*:

```js
function mostraCampo( el )
{
 var outros = document.getElementById('outros'); 
  if (selectbasic.value == Outros) 
   outros.style.display = 'block';
  else 
   outros.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
 <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="selectbasic">Item: *</label>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control">
      <option value="Banheiro">Banheiro</option>
      <option value="Rampa">Rampa</option>
   <option value="Elevador">Elevador</option>
   <option value="Vaga de Estacionamento">Vaga de Estacionamento</option>
   <option value="Outros">Outros</option>   
    </select>
  </div>
  
   <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="textinput" style="display:none" >Outros:</label>  
  <div class="col-md-7">
 <input type="textinput" name="outros"  class="form-control input-md" style="display:none">  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está confundindo as coisas.
Primeiro que na sua function você está tentando obter o `input` usando o `getElementById`, e que para isso funcione você deve adicionar um `id`ao input ou trocar o `name`pelo id como fiz.
Outra confusão é quando você diz: *select "OUTROS"*, o *Outros* é uma opção do Select e não o select em si.

Explicando meu código:

Usei o evento [onchange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) que verifica se você selecionou algum elemento no select e `this`dentro do método `mostraCampo`para pegar o objeto corrente.

Caso ainda tenha alguma duvida, deixe nos comentarios para que eu possa editar minha resposta.

*Veja funcionando:*

```js
function mostraCampo( el )
{
  var inputOutros = document.getElementById('outros');
  if (el.value === 'Outros'){ 
      inputOutros.style.display = "block";
  }
  else {
      inputOutros.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
 <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="selectbasic">Item: *</label>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <select id="selectbasic" onchange='mostraCampo(this)' name="selectbasic" class="form-control">
      <option value="Banheiro">Banheiro</option>
      <option value="Rampa">Rampa</option>
   <option value="Elevador">Elevador</option>
   <option value="Vaga de Estacionamento">Vaga de Estacionamento</option>
   <option value="Outros">Outros</option>   
    </select>
  </div>
  
   <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="textinput" style="display:none" >Outros:</label>  
  <div class="col-md-7">
 <input type="textinput" id="outros" style='display:none' class="form-control input-md" >  </div>
```